# Dynamically add item to WPF ItemsControl ObservableCollection when resizing container

Tags: wpf, resize, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of data items. The `ItemsControl` resides in a `Grid`, and the collection will only have a finite set of items (around 25-40). The `ItemsControl` has no need to scroll, but should display all items in the collection. Here's a simplified version of my current XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl>
            ....
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row=1>
        ....
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row=2>
        ....
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The `ItemsControl` only takes as much room as it needs to display the items, and if the window is resized vertically, there is empty space below the control. Using the ActualHeight of an item, or something similar, is there a way to detect when there is sufficient space underneath the control to add a new item to the collection? When shrinking the window, I'd also want to remove an item from the collection if there isn't enough room to display it.